# Local Site Defaulting to https

Tags: https

I have a weird problem. I can't preview one of my websites locally because the URL defaults to https - in all of my browsers.

I'm using MAMP PRO on a Mac. I created an alias of the problem site, but I have the same problem when I try the new URL - it defaults to https and doesn't display anything. All my other local sites display normally at http:.

Does anyone have any idea what would cause this and how I can fix it?

Edit: I should add that if I manually change the URL from https to http, it just defaults back to https.

Answer (score 1):

Find where mamp pro installed, and find where is has stored apache.
Go here and read this guide: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-disabling-ssl-v3.htm
In summary, find apache config. Most times apache.conf of apache2.conf and append `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3` to in. Then restart apache :)

Comment: I navigated to Applications > Mamp > conf > apache > httpd.conf I found this line at the end of the file: # Uncomment the next line if Apache should not accept SSLv3 connections, to learn more google for "POODLE SSLv3".
# SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 So I uncommented it and restarted MAMP Pro. However, it didn't fix the problem.